# How to access magnetometer data

Tags: ios, magnetometer, cmmotionmanager

Following [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_33), here is my attempt to access magnetometer data. Needless to say, it doesn't work.

I've gotten gyroscope and accelerometer data to work using the exact same approach, but for some reason, I get all zeroes in each axis using this one.

```
 motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];


[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
[motionManager startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:
 [NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMMagnetometerData *magnetometerData, NSError *error) {
     double x = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.x;
     double y = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.y;
     double z = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.z;

     self.magnetometerDataLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%8.4f, %8.4f, %8.4f}", x, y, z];
 }];
motionManager.magnetometerUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    double x = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.x;
    double y = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.y;
    double z = motionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.z;

    self.magnetometerDataLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%8.4f, %8.4f, %8.4f}", x, y, z];
}];
```